# How to load dll from PS module path

Tags: powershell, dll, dllimport

I have a PS module - all working fine. For a new script which is part of this module I need to load a dll from the Microsoft WindowsAPICodePack

I've added the dll to an "Assemblies" folder within the module, which is installed in the default location (C:\Program Files\WindowsPowershell\Modules\ModuleName).

The script which uses the dll works fine in test, when the dll is in a temp folder e.g. 'c:\temp', however when I run the script from the module, using the path to the dll copy in the module (C:\Program Files\WindowsPowershell\Modules\ModuleName\Assemblies\mydllname.dll) it fails to load the dll with "file not found".

I'm local administrator for the machine so I have access to the path and it also fails if I elevate Powershell before running it.

I need to load the dll from this location without amending permissions for the folder as the module is for distribution to many users via our in-house repository. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Is there a way to load the dll into the user environment as the module loads instead? This might not work either though as it seems to be a permissions issue on executing/loading dll from the modules path.

I suppose I could run a Set-Acl command against the dll in the .psm1 but this seems a bit clunky and no idea if the install-module process would have required rights?

Example code:

```
Try {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -Path $DllPath
}
Catch {
    $_
    Pause
    Break
}
```

If

```
$DllPath = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\module\dllname.dll"
```

Then it will fail

If

```
$DllPath = "C:\temp\dllname.dll"
```

Then it will succeed

**Tried**

Added the dll to the module's `Required Assemblies` in the manifest

Added this to start of the script

```
Using moduleName
Using namespace Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack
```

Same error